# looking for ideal Freecell for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, games

I used to have Windows 7 Enterprise. Until yesterday. I obviously switched to Ubuntu and the only thing I find difficult to live without is my old Freecell game. I tried some others, but they do not have any goodies I am used to. (like ctrl+z combination for undoing a stupid move) (please do not suggest Ace of Penguins, I hate it.) Is there any simple download for an average user like me?

Comment: Freecell windows version works under wine if you really really want to play the windows version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of good Linux Freecells out there, and no doubt you will get the full list (from others). I, however have a more elegant solution. If you miss MS Freecell you can install that.

My favorite method to do that would be to install Playonlinux:

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Tho you can use a gui software installer if you like. From PlayonLinux you type Freecell in the search and install. Piece of cake.

Answer (score 3):

You already tried AisleRiot Solitaire? It's a huge collection of many different one-player card games, also including FreeCell afaik. I think it comes preinstalled with Ubuntu (at least it was preinstalled on my 14.10).

Answer (score 1):

I used Kpatience (kpat). It is quite stable, good looking and it has many hotkeys like Ctrl-Z for Undoing.

Just go to the Ubuntu Software Center available on the Desktop's left side. Then enter the search text **patience**.

Kind regards and happy gaming.